# How to find the process ID associated with a particular instance of a running application on Mac

Tags: macos

In my particular case, I'm running multiple instances of RStudio (an IDE) and I want to kill one instance of the application but leave the others alone. If one instance hangs and I need to kill it, how do I do so without killing the other instances of the application that are also running? I can try to guess which process corresponds to which GUI window (instance) by looking at CPU and memory usage of each RStudio instance in Activity Monitor, but sometimes it's not possible to identify the correct instance using this method. Is there a more concrete way to identify the process ID of a particular instance of an application running on MacOS?

Comment: Can you not bring that one to the front & Cmd/Opt/Esc it? That should highlight your frontmost process as you do. [Can't test for RStudio, don't use it]

Comment: I didn't realize that Cmd-Opt-Esc selects the correct instance of the application. Accessibility Inspector also seems to work if you need the actual PID for some reason. But this method is much more convenient if all you want to do is close the instance of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bring that instance to the front, then use  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>Esc</kbd>  this will highlight the frontmost process, no PID required.